# Homotopy fixed points of KU

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-k-theory, spectra

Let $KU$ be the spectrum representing complex $K$-theory and $KO$ be the spectrum representing real $K$-theory.  Complex-conjugation of complex vector bundles lifts to a $C_2$-action on $KU$.  It's a well-known fact that $$KU^{hC_2} \simeq KO.$$

I would like to have a reasonably self-contained proof of this fact that does not require any knowledge of $\pi_* KO$.  (If I knew $\pi_* KO$, I could run the homotopy fixed point spectral sequence for $KU^{hC_2}$ and show that they have the same homotopy groups, etc.)

The proof ought to need some geometric input since I've defined $KU$ and $KO$ geometrically, and I think Atiyah's $KR$-theory is the appropriate tool to use.  Recall, $KR$-theory interpolates between $KO$ and $KU$:

- Over spaces $X$ with trivial involution, $KR(X) \cong KO(X)$.
- Over spaces of the form $X \sqcup X$ with the swap involution, $KR(X \sqcup X) \cong KU(X)$.

How do I pass from these facts about the cohomology theory $KR(-)$ to facts about spectra $KU, KO$ and their homotopy fixed points?

Comment: [This](https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0509/0509396.pdf) paper of Karoubi contains a proof using $KR$ theory.

Comment: @PavKivimae  Thanks!  I actually already took a look at that paper.  Banach algebras aside, I'm not convinced that it's not already relying on the fact that $\pi_* KO$ is 8-periodic and facts about $\eta \in \pi_* KO$ (see the end of section 7).

Comment: Oh, you want literally no knowledge of the structure of $\pi_*(KO)$. I don't know if this is possible, since you probably atleast need nilpotence of $\eta$ and $8$-periodicity for most of the arguments.